# Using Standard .so files in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm a beginner in GStreamer programming.

I created a pipeline for playing media in a file.
I would like to use `libogg.so` for decoding the ogg format files rather than `libgstogg.so`.

How can i use the this decoder in my pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

you seem to miss some basic concepts here:

- gstreamer is a framework to build media *pipelines* from *elements*
- elements are defined via a plugin-system. the plugin-files are shared-objects (.so) files
- you cannot use *just any* shared-object as a plugin (gstreamer will not recognize e.g. `libc.so` as a plugin - simply because `libc.so` does not provide a gstreamer plugin)

so in your special case you want to exchange `libgstogg.so` by `libogg.so`.

now `libgstogg.so` is a shared object, that provides the `ogg` family of gstreamer plugins.
on the other side `libogg.so` is an implementation of an ogg muxer/demuxer that has nothing to do with gstreamer.

if you want to use `libogg.so` you will have to create your own gstreamer-plugin that uses `libogg.so`. check the [documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/index.html) on how to do that.

before you do so, check what `libgstogg.so` actually does. you will disover, that it provides a gstreamer plugin that uses `libogg.so` to do the actual muxing/demuxing. it is really just the bridge that you are looking for:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstogg.so | grep ogg
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fc3f9ae7000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody is beginner in gstreamer programming it seems :)

You will have to write a program, may be C program and link it against libogg.so rather than libgstogg.so

You can achieve above easily using `cmake`

To be confirm what lib the program picked for linking,

1. You may try renaming libgstogg or
2. Running `strace` to see which location the binary picked the file
3. Create a shared library of your program and run `ldd`